# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null in else statement

Tags: reactjs

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null in else statement

```
if(count > parseInt(this.credentials.noOfusers)){
  document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('noerror').style.display = 'none';
}
else {                                               
  document.getElementById('noerror').style.display = 'block';              
  document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'none';
}
```

## html

```
<div id="noerror" style = {{display = 'none'}}>
  <button onClick={this.mpayment.bind(this, planmonth.subscriptionId)}>Payment</button>
</div>
<div id="error" style = {{display = 'none'}}>
  <button onClick={ this.deleteUsers }>Delete Users</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style={{display:this.addvisible}} key={planyear.subscriptionId}>
    <button onClick={this.ypayment}>Payment</button>
    </div>
    <div  style={{display:this.updatevisible}}>
<button onClick={ this.deleteUsers }>Delete Users</button>
</div> 
if(count > parseInt(this.credentials.numberOfUser)){
                    this.addvisible = 'none';
                    this.updatevisible='block';
                }else{
                    this.addvisible = 'block';
                    this.updatevisible='none';

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Ref`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to do DOM operation

HTML :

```
<div  id="error" style = {{display = 'none'}} ref= { (node)=>{  mynode = node  }}>
```

OR
in class-based

```
<div  id="error" style = {{display = 'none'}} ref= { (node)=>{ this.mynode = node  }}>
```

JS :

```
if(count > parseInt(this.credentials.noOfusers)){
    mynode.style.display = 'block';
}else{
    mynode.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: don't encourage him to do this kind of code. use a state to set className and mutate state in the callback. don't work direct with the dom - reference or not.

Comment: can u send me a sample for state plz